# Oracle JSON Delivery to Azure

Tags: json, oracle, azure

I have been tasked with developing a simple JSON based interface to deliver event based data from Oracle for publishing to the cloud (Azure).  Having had no prior exposure to this technology I am looking for some advice on how best to go about this.  I am aware that Oracle has well defined packages for generating JSON output from Oracle tables based on simple SQL content.  Some examples of using the Oracle packages would be much appreciated, and also how to deliver the completed JSON output to Azure.

Comment: not sure if this it would be relevant in your situation but when I want JSON from oracle I typically use the .net web api.   so after you do your sql and return it to the asp .net controller it will return the result as JSON data then you simply call your web api  as a url.  for example myapp/api/myoracletable   and myoracletable will be displayed as JSON data.

Comment: if you use oracle12c: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23560996/return-results-of-a-sql-query-as-json-in-oracle-12c

Comment: Unfortunately current Oracle version is 10.x

Comment: I updated my answer for 10g

Answer (score 0):

because you cannot use native [JSON](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/json.htm#ADXDB6246) in Oracle 12c

for 10g you need an external library

for example this one: [pljson](https://github.com/pljson/pljson)

I'd recommend this example of using PL/JSON  [Relational to JSON with PL/JSON](https://jsao.io/2015/07/relational-to-json-with-pljson/)

Comment: I have read through this documentation, however I believe my interpretation of the content is somewhat sabotaged by my expectations. Logically I was expecting to make some simple SQL statements to pick up the latest event from the database and squirt these into a file in JSON format.  What appears to be missing from the documentation is how the completed JSON content is delivered to the file, and then how this file is then delivered to the cloud.  It may be that these elements are discussed in other Oracle documents of course.

Comment: I am also not sure by what is meant by a JSON table, does this terminology imply that I first have to generate a 'temporary' table in order to generate the required output?

Comment: Just noticed that this answer is Oracle 12.x specific, unfortunately I am working against an Oracle 10.x database.

Comment: Thanks for your input are, I think this may get me part of the way there, but I'll leave the question open to see if anybody can provide information on the delivery aspect of the required solution.