# How to convert the results from a query in to a JSON in oracle 12c?

Tags: sql, json, oracle

Trying to update a new column with JSON,
i need to convert the selected data in to JSON first.

Here is my code (updated from comment):

```
SELECT a.col1 a.col2 b.col3 b.col4 
from table AS JSON
```

and I want my output to look like:

`[{"col1": "value1", "col2": 2}, {"col3": "value3", "col4": "value4"}]`

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: SELECT 
a.col1
a.col2
b.col3
b.col4
 from table AS JSON
and i want my output to look like
[{"col1": "value1", "col2": 2}, {"col3": "value3", "col4": "value4"}]

Comment: duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23560996/return-results-of-a-sql-query-as-json-in-oracle-12c

Answer (score 0):

Working solution for Oracle 12.2.0.1.0 is shown here

https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_E8F0DRCAGJJFKAMGK4AB6T2PG.html

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at APEX_JSON which comes with APEX. It is designed to backfill JSON functionality in older version of the database.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39149/apex_json.htm#AEAPI29635