# Create JSON Output from Oracle REF Cursor

Tags: json, oracle, oracle12c

Good Evening,
I am trying to output JSON from Oracle SQL Query(Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit, Hence Cannot Generate a JSON Output)

Came Across this Solution from [here](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/12232/Creating-JSON-from-Oracle-using-SYS-REFCURSOR.html)

The Output

```
{"metadata":[{"name":"EMPNO","type":"number"},{"name":"ENAME","type":"text"},{"name":"JOB","type":"text"},{"name":"DEPTNO","type":"number"}],"data":[
  {
    "EMPNO":"7369",
    "ENAME":"SMITH",
    "JOB":"CLERK",
    "DEPTNO":"20"
  }
]}]}
```

But my Expected Output is Following Below

```
 {
    "EMPNO":"7934",
    "ENAME":"MILLER",
    "JOB":"CLERK",
    "DEPTNO":"10"
  }
```

Need your Advice on how to ignore the Metadata line in the JSON Output.

Comment: If you try to understand the code written in the post, its really not all that difficult, you just need to comment that lines, which put the `metadata`

Comment: You should try PL/JSON : https://github.com/pljson/pljson. Instead of a refcursor, you could directly use the query like this to get json output: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26861590/7998591

Comment: @sudipta, Thanks for the Quick reply, But its not the Word Metadata i want to ignore, its the Metadata information it prints along with the JSON Data that is what I wanted to Ignore. I had did tried commenting the Metadata(Header_clob), it will just Print the JSON data but it also Prints Column Names too, as part of the Metadata Line.

Comment: @ Sudipta Thanks, I mistook your response as I Indeed commented some Code which puts Metadata Earlier, but I was not able to get expected JSON Output, after Commenting Some extra Looping in the Code, I got the expected result. Thanks Once again.

Answer (score -1):

It is about modifying the function that the JSON object creates. In this case it is to remove the contents of the variable l_header_clob and correct the brackets of the array.