# Evaluating dynamic PLSQL statment

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, dynamic-sql

The purpose of this proc is to combine columns of a record type into a line of text.

Example: `SALARY= 80000, POSITION=ENG, ID=8`

How can I evaluate l_stmt dynamically.

Please note I do not want to do it the traditional way by concatenation.

Open to other suggestions.

Thank you

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
(
   ID         INTEGER,
   POSITION   VARCHAR2 (32),
   SALARY     NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (ID, POSITION, SALARY)
     VALUES (1, 'ENG', '100000');

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (ID, POSITION, SALARY)
     VALUES (2, 'PROGRAMMER', '80000');

COMMIT;


CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE column_to_text (rec employee%ROWTYPE)
AS
   TYPE tb IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 (30)
      INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

   l_colnames   tb;
   l_stmt       VARCHAR2 (2500);
BEGIN
   SELECT column_name
     BULK COLLECT INTO l_colnames
     FROM sys.all_tab_cols
    WHERE table_name = 'EMPLOYEE';

   FOR i IN 1 .. l_colnames.COUNT
   LOOP
      l_stmt :=
         l_stmt || l_colnames (i) || '=' || 'REC.' || l_colnames (i) || ', ';

   END LOOP;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( l_stmt );

   --SALARY=REC.SALARY, POSITION=REC.POSITION, ID=REC.ID,
END;
```

Comment: Why on Earth would you want to do it that way?  What are you trying to accomplish?  Anyway, I don't see where in your procedure you are querying the employee table's data.

Comment: You may want to upgrade to 12.2 , `JSON_OBJECT`  will get you the output in a similar format  https://stackoverflow.com/a/41495395/7998591

Comment: @OldProgrammer As I mentioned in my question, I want to form a line of text from the columns. I don't want to list and concatenate each column the traditional way.

Comment: "I don't want to ..." - why not?

Comment: You can parse a cursor like `select * from employees` using `DBMS_SQL` and concatenate the results dynamically. http://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/refcursor-to-csv.shtml