# Generate JSON from Oracle Stored Procedure

Tags: json, oracle, stored-procedures

I would like to Generate JSON object from an Oracle stored procedure. Is there any way of doing this?

Are there any open source libraries?

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23560996/return-results-of-a-sql-query-as-json-in-oracle-12c) and looks like it is only from SQL not stored procedure

Comment: all the json_.... functions that you saw in the question you linked to are usable from pl/sql (hence in stored procedures). There's a [whole book](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adjsn/index.html) on oracle docs about JSON in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [APEX_JSON package](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.2/aeapi/Package-Overview-and-Examples.html#GUID-59567A48-7F81-4748-8998-CF3081286EC8) which you may already have installed on your database (comes with Oracle APEX).

For example (from the linked doc):

```
BEGIN
    apex_json.open_object;        -- {
    apex_json.write('a', 1);    --   "a":1
    apex_json.open_array('b');  --  ,"b":[
    apex_json.open_object;    --    {
    apex_json.write('c',2); --      "c":2
    apex_json.close_object;   --    }
    apex_json.write('hello'); --   ,"hello"
    apex_json.write('world'); --   ,"world"
    apex_json.close_all;          --  ]
                          -- }
END;
```

Comment: How to generate from stored procedure? I  don't see that anywhere

Comment: @Chatra Sorry I'm not sure what you mean?  You can't see the APEX_JSON package?  Maybe it isn't installed on your db.